# Replace NA values of subgroups in different columns with other values in separate column

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, na

My problem:

```
Tom_dog <- c(1,4,NA,6,10,5)
Joe_dog <- c(2,NA,8,10,12,5)
Theo_dog <- c(5,1,6,8,NA,7)
Gus_cat <- c(9,10,14,12,13,NA)
Walz_cat <- c(NA, 9,8,7,4,2)
Ron_cat <- c(15,13,NA,2,5,6)
df <- data.frame(Tom_dog,Joe_dog,Theo_dog,Gus_cat,Walz_cat,Ron_cat)
```

I calculate the mean for the dogs and the cats and attach it to the dataframe in a new column

```
df$dog_mean <- rowMeans(df[ , grepl("^.+(_dog)$", colnames(df))], na.rm = TRUE)
df$cat_mean <- rowMeans(df[ , grepl("^.+(_cat)$", colnames(df))], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Now, what I would like to do is replace the NA value of the dogs, with the mean of of the dog in the same row. In the second step the same thing with the cats.
I tried somethin like this, but didn't work:

```
df[ , grepl("^.+(_dog)$", colnames(df))][is.na(df[ , grepl("^.+(_dog)$", colnames(df))])]
<- df$dog_mean[is.na(df[ , grepl("^.+(_dog)$", colnames(df))])]
```

Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, you can do this with two passes of `lapply`:

```
# dogs
df[, grepl("_dog", names(df))] <- lapply(df[, grepl("_dog", names(df))],
                                       function(i) {i[is.na(i)] <- df$dog_mean[is.na(i)]; i})
# cats
df[, grepl("_cat", names(df))] <- lapply(df[, grepl("_cat", names(df))],
                                       function(i) {i[is.na(i)] <- df$cat_mean[is.na(i)]; i})
```

Here, the list that `lapply` returns is fed back into the appropriate spot in the data.frame. The `{}` make sure that the entire block of code (two lines, separated by `;` is executed in one go).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to do the transformation in a single step, you might be better off with an `lapply` call to make the conversion one column at a time (I'm using `magrittr` here just to save typing the entire first line twice:

```
library( magrittr )
df[ , grepl("^.+(_dog)$", colnames(df))] %<>%
    lapply( function( x, vals ) {
        ifelse( is.na( x ), vals, x )
    },
    vals = df$dog_mean )
```

And the same for cats:

```
df[ , grepl("^.+(_cat)$", colnames(df))] %<>%
    lapply( function( x, vals ) {
        ifelse( is.na( x ), vals, x )
    },
    vals = df$cat_mean )
```